# How does an ADB2C added via the Azure-Portal UI (OIDC) create the objectId? What about the alternativeSecurityId?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I have an existing Application which uses the objectId to identify users and store their data. It uses the built in flow for signup/signin. The company AD has been added via the Azure-Portal UI as a OIDC-Provider.

As we require the user to agree to Terms of Use before signup a custom policy was needed.
This custom policy was build using the  local & social account starter pack. The Company AD was again added as OICD-Provider.
This was done as described here: [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant-custom?tabs=applications)

The AD B2C can't find the existing user when using the technical profile to read from the AAD using the alternativeSecurityId.
But this technical profile should be used for social accounts, shouldn't it?

The problem is that if an existing user tries to login using the company AD as social login on the custom policy, the AD B2C
doesn't recognize the user and then proceeds to the signup process. Which would be the right behavior if the user wouldn't already exist.

My best guess is, that if the AD is added via the UI it creates a different alternativeSecurityId for the user or doesn't create one at all.

These are the Outputclaimstransformations of the Claimsprovider for the company AD:

```xml
<OutputClaimsTransformations>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateRandomUPNUserName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateUserPrincipalName"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateAlternativeSecurityId"/>
    <OutputClaimsTransformation ReferenceId="CreateSubjectClaimFromAlternativeSecurityId"/>
</OutputClaimsTransformations>
```

The claimstransformation used for creating the alternativeSecurityId as provided in the starter pack:

```xml
<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateAlternativeSecurityId" TransformationMethod="CreateAlternativeSecurityId">
    <InputClaims>
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="issuerUserId" TransformationClaimType="key" />
        <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" TransformationClaimType="identityProvider" />
    </InputClaims>
    <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="alternativeSecurityId" TransformationClaimType="alternativeSecurityId" />
    </OutputClaims>
</ClaimsTransformation>
```

Is there a way to get the adb2c to create the same objectId using the custom policies as it did previously?

Comment: Your best guess is incorrect, this should work. The altSecId is generated the same way, based off the ID of the user coming from the federated IdP. So it should be coming back the same in both user flows or custom policies. Compare your claims mapping between user flow and custom policy, make sure the UserId is mapped to the same claim. The other thing to check is the issuer in the Identities collection. This in custom policy is set by the identityProvider claim. Likely it is different in custom policy compared to User Flow. You can confirm the current issuer by returning a user in MS Graph -

Comment: - Api and examining the Identities collection. The read operation to find a social ID exists combined the AltSecId and Issuer into a collection and searches it in the directory. So both these things must be exactly the same. Find the current issuer that’s been set and update the identityProvider claim in the custom policy with the same string.

Comment: @JasSuri You were right! The issuer when added via ui was: "https://sts.windows.net/<guid>/" vs "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<guid>/v2.0" for the custom policy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The altSecId is generated the same way, based off the ID of the user coming from the federated IdP. So it should be coming back the same in both user flows or custom policies.

Compare your claims mapping between user flow and custom policy, make sure the UserId is mapped to the same claim. The other thing to check is the issuer in the Identities collection. This in custom policy is set by the identityProvider claim.

Likely it is different in custom policy compared to User Flow. You can confirm the current issuer by returning a user in MS Graph Api and examining the Identities collection.

The read operation to find a social ID exists combined the AltSecId and Issuer into a collection and searches it in the directory.

So both these things must be exactly the same. Find the current issuer that’s been set and update the identityProvider claim in the custom policy with the same string.